# No rollback with quarkus, mutiny and reactive postgresql

Tags: transactions, reactive-programming, quarkus, reactive-postgresql-client, mutiny

I am trying to get 3 inserts executed within the same transaction, but I am not able to get the transaction rolled back when one of the inserts fail.

I am new in the reactive world and this is my very first reactive application.

Here is a simplification of the database model:

```
EntityA 1---N EntityB
EntityA 1---N EntityC
```

I want to execute the following inserts within the same transaction:

```sql
INSERT INTO A
INSERT INTO B  --(failing query)
INSERT INTO C
```

But, when the second insert fails, the first insert does not rollback.

I've got the following classes:

- `Processor`: receives a message from kafka and triggers the inserts though a Service
- `Service`: runs the 3 inserts by using 3 DAOs
- `EntityADao`: runs the insert of the entity A
- `EntityBDao`: runs the insert of the entity B
- `EntityBDao`: runs the insert of the entity C

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class Processor {
    private final Service service;

    public Processor(final Service service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Incoming("input-channel")
    @Outgoing("output-channel")
    public Uni<Message<RequestMessage>> process(final Message<RequestMessage> message) {
        final RequestMessage rm = message.getPayload();

        return service.saveEntities(rm)
                .onFailure()
                    .recoverWithItem(e -> {
                        final String errorMessage = "There was an unexpected error while saving entities";
                        LOG.error(errorMessage, e);

                        return Result.KO;
                    })
                .flatMap(result -> {
                    rm.setResult(result);

                    return Uni.createFrom()
                        .item(Message.of(rm), message::ack))
                });
    }
}
```

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class WorkerService {
    private final EntityADao entityADao;
    private final EntityBDao entityBDao;
    private final EntityCDao entityCDao;

    public WorkerService(final EntityADao entityADao,
                         final EntityBDao entityBDao,
                         final EntityCDao entityCDao) {
        this.entityADao = entityADao;
        this.entityBDao = entityBDao;
        this.entityCDao = entityCDao;
    }

    @Transactional(TxType.REQUIRED)
    public Uni<Result> saveEntities(final RequestMessage requestMessage) {
        return Uni.createFrom().item(Result.OK)
                // Save Entity A
                .flatMap(result -> {
                    LOG.debug("(1) Saving EntityA ...");

                    return entityADao.save(requestMessage.getEntityAData());
                })
                // Save Entity B
                .flatMap(result -> {
                    LOG.debug("(2) Saving EntityB ...");

                    return entityBDao.save(requestMessage.getEntityBData());
                })
                // Save Entity C
                .flatMap(result -> {
                    LOG.debug("(3) Saving EntityC ...");

                    return entityCDao.dao(requestMessage.getEntityCData());
                })
                // Return OK
                .flatMap(result -> Uni.createFrom().item(Result.OK));
    }
}
```

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class EntityADao {
    private final PgPool client;

    public EntityADao(final PgPool client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    @Transactional(TxType.MANDATORY)
    public Uni<Result> save(final EntityAData entityAData) {
        return client
                .preparedQuery(
                        "INSERT INTO A(col1, col2, col3) " +
                            "VALUES ($1, $2, $3)")
                .execute(Tuple.of(entityAData.col1(), entityAData.col2(), entityAData.col3()))
                .flatMap(pgRowSet -> {
                    LOG.debug("Inserted EntityA!");

                    return Result.OK;
                });
    }
}
```

`EntityBDao` and `EntityCDao` are like `EntityADao`.

I have already added the following dependencies to `pom.xml`:

- `quarkus-smallrye-context-propagation`
- `quarkus-narayana-jta`

**Why when the `INSERT B` query in `EntityBDao` fails, the previously executed query (`INSERT A`) does not rollback? What do am I missing? What would I have to change in order to get this working?**

Comment: The DB reactive clients do not use the @Transactional annotation, you need to use the transactions are explained in https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-sql-clients#transactions

Answer (score 4):

This paragraph recently added to our Quarkus documentation should help you with this: https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-sql-clients#transactions .

It specifically explains how to deal with transactions when using the Reactive SQL clients.

Comment: After reading https://quarkus.io/guides/transaction#reactive-extensions, https://quarkus.io/guides/context-propagation#usage-example-with-mutiny and https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-sql-clients#transactions it was not clear to me the correct way of working with transactions and reactive sql clients. I thought that it was possible to combine `@Transactional` and `Mutiny` and reactive sql client. I've followed the example in the link and it works! Thank you